# Plaid API not allowing me to access all banks in development mode

Tags: oauth, hyperlink, plaid

I'm trying to use the plaid API to connect to personal bank accounts. On Sandbox mode everything works fine and I am able to access all institutions. But when I go on development mode I cannot access some banks such as Wells Fargo and Chase, which make it difficult to test on personal bank accounts. This is the message I get when I click on those institutions.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOH4n.png)

Meanwhile I can access log in under other real bank institutions such as TD Bank. Does anyone know how to fix this so I can log in under all banks.

I've tried refreshing the api keys, and using a brand new set of api keys and nothing has worked

Answer (score 1):

Plaid supports only a set of financial institutions in US under sandbox environment.You can view it through the following link.

https://plaid.com/docs/sandbox/institutions/

In order to access the other financial institutions (such as chase), you have to have production access.

Below is mentioned in plaid website.
In the US and Canada, OAuth requires Production access; you cannot connect to US OAuth institutions in the Development environment without having received both OAuth approval and Production approval. You can, however, test OAuth in the Sandbox environment, using Sandbox-only institutions, without needing Production approval.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Production access yet? Per the Plaid docs at https://plaid.com/docs/link/oauth/#request-production-access-from-plaid “In the US and Canada, OAuth requires Production access; you cannot connect to US OAuth institutions in the Development environment without having received both OAuth approval and Production approval.”

Comment: Do you know if there is anyways to log in with development mode, since development mode is supposed to let you log in with live credentials. Also since production access is pretty expensive.

Comment: @AyushRana you can still make the calls in development mode, but you need to have production access / approval before they will work in development mode for oauth institutions