# Plaid Quickstart Development/Production Failure

Tags: plaid

In Plaid's QuickStart example, everything works in "sandbox" mode. In "development" and "production", certain banks—including most major banks like Chase—give [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOH4n.png).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76379471/plaid-api-not-allowing-me-to-access-all-banks-in-development-mode) states that the plaid quickstart example can fail for some banks if you don't have production access. I have production access and it's still failing. ([proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ8T1.png))

What is wrong with the Plaid API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you don't have OAuth registration completed yet for those institutions. You can check the status of OAuth registration on the Dashboard at https://dashboard.plaid.com/settings/compliance/us-oauth-institutions